# Macro replacement for macro-function

Tags: c, macros, preprocessor

I'm experimenting with macro replacement for functions.

[LIVE EXAMPLE](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aa893ad69cac1092)

Here is the simple vararg macro definition:

```
#define FOO(a, ...) printf(a, ##__VA_ARGS__)
```

So when we define

```
FOO("1"); //preprocesses to printf("1"), ',' is truncated

FOO("1", 2, 3); //preprocesses to printf("1", 2, 3), ',' is left unchanged
```

Without `##` preceding `__VA_ARGS__` the ',' does not truncated. So I expected that ## operator does the job, but its definition in the standard is a bit blurred. Here are some quotes:

`6.10.3.3(p2)`:

> if an argument consists of no preprocessing tokens, the parameter is
>   replaced by a placemarker preprocessing token instead

`6.10.3.3(p3)`:

> For both object-like and function-like macro invocations, before the
>   replacement list is reexamined for more macro names to replace, each
>   instance of a `##` preprocessing token in the replacement list (not from
>   an argument) is deleted and the preceding preprocessing token is
>   concatenated with the following preprocessing token.

From the 2 sections I don't see any reason that in the invokation `FOO("1")` expands to `printf("1")`, not `printf(1,)`. `__VA_ARGS__` consits of no preprocessing tokens.

So if we define

```
#define FOO(a, b) printf(a, ##b)
```

Why does `FOO(1,)` expand to `printf(1,)`? `b` also consits of no preprocessing tokens here.

Comment: The comma swallowing behavior is a GCC extension.

Comment: @jxh So this is not portable? Reasonable...

Comment: @jxh The only portable way is to declare macros as `#define SOME_MACRO_FUNCTION(...) printf(__VA_ARGS__)`?